# Derive a tangent using the AceGen package

Tags: finite-element-method, code-request, acegen

I want to derive the algorithmic tangent of a material model, but all I have given is the potential and the flow function. Are there any exmaple codes or tutorials for the implementation with AceGen? All I found were tutorials for the FEM-Implementation.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @ acegen 
Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @acegen  On AceFEM/AceGen home [page](http://symech.fgg.uni-lj.si/Download.htm) you can find PDF and notebook documentation for both packages. You can also download trial version of packages and explore documentation by evaluating it.